# Find a function $ f : R^2 → R $ such that $ f(λv) = λf(v) $, $\forall \lambda \in R, v ∈ R^2$, yet $f$ is not linear.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

> Find a function $ f : R^2 → R $ such that $ f(λv) = λf(v) $, $\forall v ∈ R^2$, yet $f$ is not linear.

I've been at this for ages, and can't seem to find a single function. I've tried using all general functions such as trigonometric, exponents, etc. Any ideas?

Comment: Whoops, edited...

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate of some older question, whose location I cannot remember unfortunately

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint** The condition just means that $f$ is linear on each $1$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$, but imposes no further conditions, so its behavior on one subspace need not have any connection with its behavior on another.

> For example, we can define $f(x, y)$ to be $x$ on lines of positive slope, (equivalently, in the open first and fourth quadrants, that is, where $x y > 0$) to be and $0$ elsewhere.

Comment: @Seth Cheers, I misread the question, and just fixed it.

Comment: The above function seems to satisfy the conditions for a linear map. Is this the case?

Comment: No, definitely not: For example, $f((1, 0) + (1, 1)) = f(2, 1) = 2 \neq 1 = 0 + 1 = f(1, 0) + f(1, 1)$.

Comment: Of course, my mistake ! Thanks a million.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad to help.

Answer (score 3):

This function is determined by its values on the unit circle,  it grows linearly on each ray emanating from $(0,0)$, and we have to take care that $f(-{\bf v})=-f({\bf v})$. Therefore we may start with an arbitrary $2\pi$-periodic function $g:\>\phi\mapsto g(\phi)$ satisfying $g(\phi+\pi)=-g(\phi)$. The (complex) Fourier series of such a function contains only terms of odd frequency:
$$g(\phi)=\sum_k c_{2k+1}e^{(2k+1)i\phi}\ .$$
A simple nontrivial example would be $g(\phi):=\sin(3\phi)$. Given such a $g$ we can define
$$f({\bf v}):=|{\bf v}|\> g\bigl(\arg{\bf v}\bigr)\quad({\bf v}\ne{\bf 0}),\qquad f({\bf 0}):=0\ .$$

Comment: One still needs to ensure that the resulting function $f$ is nonlinear: For example, for $g(\phi) = \sin \phi$, $f$ is the linear function $(x, y) \mapsto y$.

Comment: @Travis: Thank you for spotting the slip.

Comment: Cheers, and a very nice answer, by the way. (+1)